# jquery droppable: class.each cycles once more than the number of classed elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Refer to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/af8tv9bL/11/)

I am using jQuery to move items between elements. Once the item is dropped onto the new element, I want to pull out the text of the item (it's inside a `<div>`).

The `$('.box-item').each(function()...` piece of code always runs one time more than the total number of items with class of `.box-item`.

How do I capture the text from the item that is being dropped only once?

How to test (refer to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/af8tv9bL/11/))

1. Enter 4 items into the textarea (new line between each one): A, B,
   C, D
2. Click on "populate" (the items are created in
   `mainContainer`)
3. click on "add group"
4. Drag items from
   `mainContainer`over to one of the containers on the right

Here is the jQuery code:

```
    $("[id^=container]").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var elemId = $(this).attr("id");
            var itemid = $(event.originalEvent.toElement).attr("itemid");
            var q = 1;
            $('.box-item').each(function() {
                // this section always runs one more time than the number of items
                console.log (q);
                var aaa= $(this).closest(".box-container").attr("id");  
                console.log ("parent div: " + aaa);             

                q++;
                if ($(this).attr("itemid") === itemid) {
                    // this section gets executed twice
                    var abc = $(this).closest(".box-container").attr("id"); 
                    console.log ("from: " + abc);               
                    console.log ("append2:" + "<div id='" + elemId + "'>" );
                    $(this).appendTo("#" + elemId);

                    // what is in the div?
                    var txt = $(this).text();
                    console.log(txt);
                    var abc = $(this).closest(".box-container").attr("id");
                    console.log ("to: " + abc);                 
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: maybe the extra box-item is the one being dragged (duplicate one) and that element still exists on drop event.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely counting the item in the container from where is was being moved as well as the one that triggers the drop event in the destination container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your selector like:

```
$('.box-item:not(.ui-draggable-dragging)').each(function() {
```

and it works. The draggable clone's class is also counted..

Comment: As you were replying with the answer, I just noticed a difference in `$(this)` when I dumped the objects for the extra one and saw that additional dragging class.

`[div.btn.btn-default.box-item.ui-draggable.ui-draggable-handle, context: div.btn.btn-default.box-item.ui-draggable.ui-draggable-handle]

[div.btn.btn-default.box-item.ui-draggable.ui-draggable-handle.ui-draggable-dragging, context: div.btn.btn-default.box-item.ui-draggable.ui-draggable-handle.ui-draggable-dragging]`